# Confirmation propmt design in Api.ai

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am designing an API.ai intent which gets the email from user and update in the system.

I am trying to design a confirmation prompt in which needs to compare the two emails and only then update the value.

The immediate solution that I can think of is, create a session in node.js and compare the values of both. But, I feel there must be some other elegant solution.

Comment: Hey, just wondering if you got a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Used follow up intents available in API.ai to achieve it. Take a look at the documentation. :-)